# IIS7 buffer size limit

Tags: c#, iis-7, size, buffer, limit

My problem happens when trying to download a video file via http request
in the following operating systems using IIS7:
win2008 32Bit, Win2008 R2 64Bit

Currently works fine on: win2003 , vista64 (IIS6)

Problem description:
When users request a file larger than 256mb via C# they get a limited file, even when
using Content-Length param it seems that the file get the right size but not the full
content.

When requesting the URL of the file, I get the full file, the problem occurs only via
the C# script, also the C# response that the full buffer was sent to the user.

I've changed the IIS7 settings in the article:

http://blog.twinharbor.com/2011/07/28/fixing-iis7-maximum-upload-size/

and still it doesn't work.

Also, there are no remarks or errors anywhere.

Please find a sample of my code:

```
var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; 
context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255");
context.Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
context.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
System.IO.Stream iStream = null;

// Buffer to read 100K bytes in chunk:
byte[] buffer = new Byte[100000];

// Length of the file:
int length=0;

// Total bytes to read:
long dataToRead=0;

// Identify the file to download including its path.
string filepath = u.Trim(BigFile);

// Identify the file name.
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);

Start.Value = u.Time();

try
{
    iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);
    dataToRead = iStream.Length;

    context.Response.Charset = "";
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";    

    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataToRead.ToString());

    while (dataToRead > 0)
    {
        if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 100000);

            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length); 
            context.Response.Flush(); 
            buffer = new Byte[100000];
            dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
        }
        else
        {
            dataToRead = -1;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    context.Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (iStream != null)
    {
        iStream.Close();
    }
    context.Response.Close();
}
```

I'll appericiate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding `context.Response.BufferOutput = false;` to your code?

Comment: I just tried it - it didn't make any change :(